# How to verify whether an electrical appliance is properly grounded?

Tags: grounding, safety, testing, electrocution

I read that an electrical appliance/equipment that is not properly grounded can kill people, especially if it uses mains socket where the current drawn can be high. In fact, even a simple microphone can kill. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leslie_Harvey

How to verify whether an electrical appliance is properly grounded to protect my family?

Comment: PAT it ... with a Portable Appliance Tester. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_appliance_testing

Comment: That will confirm that the appliance case is properly connected to the earth pin on its plug (if it’s not permanently wired-in) but will not check all the way back to earth.  The OP isn’t entirely clear on what’s being asked.

Comment: You can feel small leakage current with the underside of your forearm. I once had an espresso machine, when plugged into a 2-wire extension cord, would give a tingle when I brushed my arm against it. I immediately installed a proper 3-wire extension cord.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re at all uncertain, get a professional to check for you, it’s as simple as that.  If you are a professional then you’ll measure the resistance between the device in question and a known-good earthing point.  Electricians probably have a dedicated instrument for doing this but the way I’ve done it in the lab is to pass a known current (e.g. 1A) from the device to the ground point and measure the voltage drop, 1V corresponds to 1 ohm of resistance.  For a domestic appliance 5ohms appears to be a rule of thumb, but check the regulations for your country/jurisdiction.

If an appliance that draws 10A were to pass all its load current to earth then it could present 50V if it were touched, this is unlikely to result in electrocution.

Comment: It is certainly true that: "an electrical appliance/equipment that is not properly grounded can kill people".